# MySQL: Using variables inside SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, variables, select

Please have a look at the below statement

```
INSERT INTO Ongoing_Fees (currentDate, Gross_Fee, Insurance_Fee, Submit_Fee)
    SELECT current_timestamp, New.Gross_Fee,
           @InsuranceFee := (New.Gross_Fee)*(p.E_Fee/100),
           @SubmitFee := @InsuranceFee-(p.s_Fee/100)
    FROM Portfolio p
    WHERE p.idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio;
```

Here I am using 2 user defines variables, `@InsuranceFee` and `@SubmitFee`. As you can see, you can get the `@SubmitFee` by deducting a value from `@InsuranceFee`.

Now, in order to this to work, the `@InsuranceFee` "must" be evaluated first. However [MySQL document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) says below

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> SET @a = @a + 1; For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get
>   the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following
>   statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then
>   do an assignment second:
>
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...; However, the order of evaluation for
>   expressions involving user variables is undefined.

So, what is the best way I can use variables inside `SELECT` ?

**UPDATE**

May be first assigning the values into variables using seperate SELECT statement is better? something like below...

```
 SET   @InsuranceFee :=    New.Gross_Fee * ((SELECT E_Fee FROM Portfolio WHERE idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio)/100);

 SET   @SubmitFee := @InsuranceFee - ((SELECT s_FeeFROM Portfolio WHERE idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio)/100)

    INSERT INTO Ongoing_Fees (currentDate, Gross_Fee, Insurance_Fee, Submit_Fee)
           current_timestamp, New.Gross_Fee,
                   @InsuranceFee ,
                   @SubmitFee
```

Comment: Use [9.4 User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) in this context is unsafe, I would be looking for new options (perhaps using a [13.6.6 Cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html)) to reach the goal.

Comment: Why do you need to use `user-defined variables` in this case at all?  Just use `(New.Gross_Fee)*(p.E_Fee/100)-(p.s_Fee/100)`

Comment: @sgeddes: Are you willing to use something like  `((New.Gross_Fee)*(p.E_Fee/100))-((((New.Gross_Fee)*(p.E_Fee/100))*(p.I_Fee/100))+(((New.Gross_Fee)*(p.E_Fee/100)-(((Gross_Fee)*(p.E_Fee/100))*(p.I_Fee/100)))*0.2))`. This is my real query stuff..

Comment: As you can see in the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/877c1/4) your choice is completely valid, however, your choice must do two queries on the `Portfolio` table. The solution proposed by @sgeddes gets the two values in a single sub-query and avoiding the use of [9.4 User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) as you can see in the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/877c1/3).

Answer (score 0):

`User-defined variables` weren't meant to be used like this.  As mentioned in my comment, no reason to not just write it all out.  However, if you just prefer the temporary syntax, you could always use a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO Ongoing_Fees (currentDate, Gross_Fee, Insurance_Fee, Submit_Fee)
SELECT ct, gross_fee, InsuranceFee, InsuranceFee-SubmitFee
FROM (
    SELECT current_timestamp ct, 
       New.Gross_Fee,
       New.Gross_Fee*p.E_Fee/100 as InsuranceFee,
       p.s_Fee/100 as SubmitFee
    FROM Portfolio p
    WHERE p.idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio
) T
```

Comment: @Sniper -- why would you want to run 3 sql statements when you can do it all in 1?  Do you have some other requirement saying you must use `user-defined variables`?  The subquery would be a better approach and could utilize temporary values.  With that said, nothing wrong with writing it all out in my opinion.

Comment: Nothing wrong, but super hard to edit. For an example, the query I gave in my comment, can you edit it easily? Apart from that, there are various places where we have to use conditions, like "If this record do not exists then 0 is the value, else 1 is the value" etc etc. When you have 3-4 conditions like that, writing it at "once" may not be a problem, but when something went wrong, very hard to read and edit unless it is written clearly using variables.